# Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed

Tags: android

I am getting this error when adding third party library as aar, This issue is due to the custom classes used by that third party library. This asan.aar used another third party library, of which classes are not found.Is there problem with that aar file?. Please let me know the possible way to resolve this issue.

Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\44008.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\asan.aar\19e3b5ff8a756f7762a10b1ff6978000\res\layout\activity_all_task_list.xml:16: AAPT: error: attribute tab_divider_width (aka com.secure.app:tab_divider_width) not found.